# How many natural value of n such that $n^5+2n^4+n-1$ is prime number?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers

From above polynomial, I can only get one value to make it prime.

The value, I guess, is only one.

For $n=1$, we got:

$$(n^5+2n^4+n-1)= 1+2+1-1= 3 \quad\text{(prime)}$$

But, I cannot find the other value of $n$, such that the polynomial is prime.

My question: How to prove that the solution is trivial?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint:

$$ n^5+2n^4+n-1 = (n^2+n-1) (n^3+n^2+1)$$

Comment: how can I use your hint to verify that the solution is trivial? thanks

Comment: @akusaja:  for the expression to be prime, one of the factors must be $1$.  So set each factor to $1$ and see what values of $n$ work.

Comment: @akusaja: Check for which values of $n$, either one of the components is equal to $1$. These are the only values of $n$ for which the value of the polynomial is **possibly** prime (in order to ensure that it is, you'll have to check the value of the other component).

Comment: I think it was misleading of Clement to label it a hint, because it is in fact the answer. Verify that in fact $(n^2 + n - 1)(n^3 + n^2 + 1) = n^5 + 2n^4 + n - 1$ (the quickest way would be to type "(n^2 + n - 1)(n^3 + n^2 + 1)" into Wolfram Alpha and seeing what it gives you under "Alternate forms"). This means that $n^5 + 2n^4 + n - 1$ can be expressed as the product of two integers. If this number is prime, then it has *only one* representation as a product of two integers. But $(n^2 + n - 1) > 1$ if $n > 1$. I'm out of characters but you can figure out the rest yourself easily enough.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an answer, as there is still (a reasonably small) amount of work to do after this factorization, as your comment also points out.